# Can't modify an object from function using `new` keyword

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I'm trying to execute the following code and can't understand why don't the line `person.Name = "anton";` work? The output of the program is "colin".

```
class Person
{
    public string Name;
}

class MainClass
{
    public static void MyMethod(Person person)
    {
        person.Name = "colin";
        person = new Person();
        person.Name = "anton";
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        Person person = new Person();
        person.Name = "felix";
        MyMethod(person);
        Console.WriteLine(person.Name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you specify the `ref` or `out` keyword, [function parameters are passed by value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/passing-parameters) in C#, even if the type is a reference type.

"Passing by value" means creating a **copy** of the original variable, which for reference types means the copy of the reference (not the actual object, the object is not copied, and is simply "pointed to" by both the variable and the parameter).

This means that the `person` parameter inside `MyMethod` is a copy of the `person` variable from the `Main` method, so assigning a new instance to this parameter won't affect the original variable.

So changing the properties of the instance inside the function *will* affect the original instance, until the parameter starts pointing to a different object (the point where you instantiate a new `Person` inside `MyMethod`).

Answer (score 2):

Think of the sequence of events that happen:

- `Main` creates a `Person`
- `Main` passes a reference to `Person` into `MyMethod`
- `MyMethod` makes a modification to `Main`'s `Person`. This is modification #1
- `MyMethod` *replaces* the reference to the object from `Main` with a reference to a new `Person` object. At this point, `Main`'s `person` variable and `MyMethod`'s `person` parameter are referencing two different objects.
- `MyMethod` modifies its `Person` object (modification #2), and returns
- `Main`'s person shows the result of the first modification, before the object has been replaced by `MyMethod`'s invocation of `new`.

If you would like to permit reassignments to `person` inside `MyMethod`, you need to pass the variable by reference.